# Displaying string in list and taking key as input

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

This is my dropdown list

```html
<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="NoValue"><br /></option>
    <c:forEach var="route_desc" items="${routes}">
        <option>
            <c:if test="${not empty route_desc}">
                <c:out value="${route_desc}" /> 
            </c:if> 
        </option>
    </c:forEach> 
</select>
```

In my class I took a list and then added one

```
routes.add(routeDetailsPk);
routes.add(route_description);
```

Now I want to display the route_description only but when a user selects a value i want routeDetailsPk to come as a value. How to do it ? Currently it shows all the values

Comment: You shouldn't store Strings that represent different things (pk and description) in a single list. Use a `List<Route>`, where `Route` is a class having a `pk` field and a `description` field. Java is an OO language. Use objects.

Comment: You should create an entity class called `Route` that holds both `routeDetailsPk` and `route_description` and store a `List<Route>` as request attribute.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, can i use a map instead to store it by key value pair, taking routeDetailsPk as key (as it is a pk it will always be unique).. ?

but the problem with this approach is how to iterate it and achieve the asked functionality ?

Comment: You can but its still not the right way todo it

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i need a quick fix for that, i only have access to this much code only

Comment: @bcsb1001 how will that help me to iterate in jsp using jstl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way through which we can display the value and select the key using map and jstl

```
                    <c:forEach var="route_desc" items="${routes}">
                        <option value="${route_desc.key}">
                        <c:if test="${not empty route_desc}">
                             <c:out value="${route_desc.value}" />   
                        </c:if> 
                        </option>
                    </c:forEach>
```